# Resizing of partitions taking too long in Debian 6 installer

Tags: debian, partition, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I had a Windows 7 PC, with three partitions on it:

1. The default Windows partition (~300GB in size, primary)
2. Some system stuff Windows 7 needs (100MB in size, primary)
3. A partition called `Shared`, that I saved all my media and data to (487.5GB in size, logical).

I wanted to dual boot Debian 6 (for programming) and Windows 7 (for video games).

I have intended for the `Shared` partition to be used both by Debian 6 and Windows 7, so I have formatted it with NTFS prior to moving files on it and trying to install Debian 6.

Now, with all of my files in place, I thought it was time to install Debian 6, from the 600MB CD image.

I put the disc in, and rebooted my computer from it.

Then, I chose the graphical install; there were some error messages about missing network firmware, a problem which I chose to solve once the whole system is running, but all in all everything went smoothly up to the disk partitioning point.

I chose to shrink the `Shared` partition by 50GB, in order to create a new partition on which I would install Debian 6 on.

**However, it has been over half an hour since the resize of the (logical) partition was started, and the progress bar is still displaying "Please wait".**

What is going on? 
 Is this normal? 
 How much longer will I need to wait? 
 Am I at risk of losing parts of my HDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue resolved itself.

It seems like the installer wasn't updating the progress-bar, and in a little under 45 minutes, the new 50GB partition was successfully created and marked as "free space".

Answer (score 3):

Quick calculation: Worst case, resizing or moving a partition might need to read/write all of that partition's data once or even more.  Modern spinning hard drives sustain around 100 MB/sec.  So resizing 480 GB could easily take 1.5 hours, even before taking seek times into account.